# Name resolution in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was reading this [article](http://umumble.com/blogs/javascript/163/) and I have some questions  please:

considering this code :

```
1:   var a = 1;
2:   function b () {
3:       a = 10;
4:       return;
5:       function a() {}
6:   }
7:   b();
8:   alert(a);
```

this will alert 1. ( my question is why ? )

the article states its related to *Name resolution*.

Name resolutions (according to the article ) is being determined by this order:

```
1. Internal mechanisms of language: for example, in all scopes are available “this” and “arguments”.
2. Formal parameters: the functions can be named as the formal parameters, which scope is limited to the function body.
3. Function declarations: declared in the form of function foo() {}.
4. Variable declarations: for example, var foo;.
```

line #3 suppose to change the value of the global a.
but the function a(){...} have a priorty over the inside a declaration ( If i understood correctly)
and thats why is alerts 1

p.s. if i remove line #5 , it will alert 10.

> In general, if a name is already defined, it will never be redefined
>   by another entity with the same name. That is the function declaration
>   has a priority over the declarations of the variable with the same
>   name. But this does not mean that the value of a variable assignment
>   does not replace the function, just its definition will be ignored.

I dont understand that part :

> But this does not mean that the value of a variable assignment does
>   not replace the function

so 2 questions please :

- Did I understand correctly the reason for alerting [1](http://umumble.com/blogs/javascript/163/)
- What does the above line means ? (the misunderstood part)

thanks.

Comment: i know this isn't an answer, but couldn't we just give functions and variables proper names and not worry about what happens under ficticious circumstances?

Comment: @jbabey some people like to go deeper into things to see how they works in different scenarios. this is one of them. the name is not importand here . its just an example.

Comment: My apologies, Royi, for posting the same article.  Thank you for graciously bringing that to my attention.

Comment: It seems like the article in question is now available at http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did I understand correctly the reason for alerting 1

Yes

> *"But this does not mean that the value of a variable assignment does not replace the function"*
>   What does the above line means ? (the misunderstood part)

It just means that although a function with name `a` is already defined, `a = 10` is still going to be executed, i.e. after that line `a` does not refer to a function anymore but to `10`.

I assume they wanted to relax the previous statement a bit and avoid that people incorrectly think that because the function declaration is executed first, the assignment would not take place anymore.

---

Function and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope. So the code is equivalent to:

```
1:   var a = 1;
2:   function b () {
3:       function a() {}
4:       a = 10;
5:       return;
6:   }
7:   b();
8:   alert(a);
```

`function a() {...}` creates a symbol (variable) `a` in the local scope and its value is the very same function. The next line, `a = 10;`, then assigns a new value to that symbol, namely a number.

```
var a = 1;
function b () {
     function a() {} // creates a new local symbol `a`, shadowing the outer `a`
     // until here, `a` refers to the function created 
     // created by the above declaration
     a = 10; // now a new value is assigned to the local symbol/variable `a`
     // from here on, `a` is `10`, not a function
     return;
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Comment: , Changing #3 to `window.a = 10;` will alert 10 , so what is going on here ? http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/KSUsF/

Comment: Well, if you run the code in global scope, then `var a = 1;` creates a global variable and `window.a = 10` **explicitly** assigns `10` to the global variable `a`.

Comment: doesn't the a in line #4 is the same as the global ?

Comment: No... I thought you knew this... `a` refers to the symbol in local scope which was created by `function a(){...}`.

Comment: so `function a() {}` acts like `var a;` ( which creating a local scope `a` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var a = 1;
function b () {
    var a = 10;
}
b();
alert(a);
```

does the above example make sense to you? Yes? Good, then you understand the difference between local and global scope...

```
var a = 1;
function b () {
    a = 10;
    var a;
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Does this example make sense to you? Yes? Then you understand that it does not matter where a variable is declared in a function, it will always be declared when first entering the function.

```
var a = 1;
function b () {
    a = 10;
    var a = function() { };
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Now, does this example make sense? Yes? Then you understand dynamic typing. A variable can be assigned a function as a value and then can be overwritten  with a integer such as 10.

```
var a = 1;
function b () {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() { }
}
b();
alert(a);
```

Now your example should make sense because we are just changing the way we declare a, but its the same thing.

Comment: "A variable can be assigned a function as a value and then can be overwritten with a integer" - true, but not the case here. The function assignment is never executed because it follows a `return` statement. It is only the `var a;` that gets hoisted.

Comment: @pimvdb function declarations are hoisted along with their body - it does not get split out into seperate declaration/assignment statements.

Comment: I thought you were referring to `var a = function() { };` with that sentence. Note the difference with a function declaration.

Comment: @pimvdb is correct, my bad. The variable a gets defined, assigned the value 10 and then overwritten with the function value. I wanted to get the point across that that it doesn't matter what a is associated with at first site because it can be overwritten with any value. I guess my example here was not the best, good catch.

Comment: @jbabey I dont understand. The function has a priority over the `var a`  , so if it has a priority why does `var a` still executed ?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of hoisting, both variable declarations and function declarations are hoisted. Therefor, here's what's happening:

```
var a; // a is declared (hoisted)
function b () { // function declaration (hoisted)
    function a () {} // function declaration (hoisted)
    a = 10; // an assignment to the local a that was hoisted, not the outer a
    return;
}
a = 1; // initialization (not hoisted)
b(); // hoist inside b's scope causes an inner a to be modified
alert(a); // alerts 1 since the outer a was never modified
```

Comment: No, the function is really created: http://jsfiddle.net/mwLVD/. The assignment just overwrites the existing symbol with another value.

Comment: @FelixKling the function `a` is created? i thought only the name is hoisted, not the assignment (does this not happen with functions?)

Comment: But it's not an assignment, it's a function **declaration**. `function a() {...}` is different than `a = function() {...}` (and that's exactly the difference).

Comment: @FelixKling you are right; good to know! "function declaration ('bar' and the function body get hoisted)" [source](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

Comment: @FelixKling i have edited my answer to reflect this new information. thanks again.